# Solve for θ: $y = \arctan\Bigl(\frac{x· \sin(θ)- \sin(θ·x)}{x·\cos(θ)-\cos(θ·x)}\Bigr)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm stuck here: $$\tan(y)=\frac{x·\sin(θ)-\sin(θ·x)}{x·\cos(θ)-\cos(θ·x)}$$

Comment: Is $x$ an integer or any real?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question under another user name ?

Comment: No, sir. Is it a common question?
I thought it was an impossible one, until I constructed a graph; it's very easy to (using θ = x, and y = y on the Cartesian plane) trace from the y-coordinate to my desired answer for θ [x-coordinate], but I can't seem to figure out how to solve the equation. Why, has this question been asked before? Can you provide a link to the answer?

Comment: And, may I ask, why the edited insertion of backslashes? The appearance outside of the mathjax code has not changed at all, correct?

Comment: In fact, I could simply find the intersection mathematically with a horizontal line [y = n], to get the answer I'm looking for, but if there's a way to simplify this formula for θ, I would really be interested to see it, and especially understand the steps.

Comment: And I believe $x$ is any real. I think that in this case, it shouldn't matter. It could be either.

Comment: In which context did you find this equation ?